# How can i pass output associative array of pl/sql to java?

Tags: java, jdbc, plsql

For Nested table i have done it in follwing way?
This is pl/sql stored procedure.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST(
activationStartDate IN DATE,
activationEndDate IN DATE,
deActivationStartDate IN DATE,
deActivationEndDate IN DATE
Out_Entity OUT TEST1.RefCsr
)
AS
FirstNameListTable LIST_TABLE;

{--COMMENT :LIST_TABLE is nested table :create or replace TYPE "LIST_TABLE" as table     of varchar2(20);-----Nested Table Declaration
/
}

 totalSameFirstName NUMBER;
 j NUMBER := 1;
 BEGIN



 SELECT first_name BULK COLLECT INTO FirstNameListTable FROM Employee where start_date between activationStartDate AND activationEndDate 
MINUS 
SELECT first_name FROM Employee where start_date between deActivationStartDate AND deActivationEndDate

OPEN Out_Entity FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(
                                           CAST (
                                                FirstNameListTable AS LIST_TABLE
                                             )
                                ) Nos;

  END;
   /
```

My JavaCode is

```
--First getConnection
--prepare sql string : sql = "{ Call Test(?,?,?,?,?) } ";
--Use prepareCall function on Connection object and passed this sql string and retrived CallableStatement class object.
stmt.setTimestamp(1,activationStartDate);
stmt.setTimestamp(2,activationEndDate);
stmt.setTimestamp(3,deActivationStartDate);
stmt.setTimestamp(4,deActivationEndDate);
stmt.registerOutParameter(5,-10);
stmt.execute();
List result = new ArrayList();
         ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)stmt.getObject(5);
        int i=0;
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            System.out.println(i+". "+rs.getString(1));
            i++;
        }
```

Then what if i want to select more than one column from EMPLOYEE and pass to my javaCode......How my javaCode and Pl/Sql will look like?

Comment: This question seems to answer your too.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457933/creating-package-level-associative-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use nest loop

for example in the result set get the column count value

and try like this

```
List<List> result = new ArrayList()<List>;
List col = new ArrayList();

ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)stmt.getObject(5);
ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();

        int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            col = new ArrayList();
            for(int j=1;j<numberOfColumns;j++)
                col.add(rs.getString(j);

            result.add(col);
        }
```

here first loop for getting the rows and the nested loop to getting the columns value
this value are store in the col list object and need to each time create new object